# I want to create bootstrap image container and modal from c# codebehind as per the Number of items and images i'm getting from database

Tags: asp.net, .net, twitter-bootstrap, c#-4.0, bootstrap-modal

I want to create bootstrap modal and image container from c# code behind as per the Number of items and images i'm getting from database.
Kindly suggest me how should i do it. how to do html code in c#..

I want to show like below and generate only n number of image container as per images coming from database. Thanks in advance.
[image: Image Container]

[image: Modal]

```
<div class="row">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: -60px">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="jumbotron" style="background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.0);">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-image="images/r5.jpg"
                                data-target="#image-gallery">
                                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="img1" class="img-responsive" ImageUrl="images/r5.jpg"
                                    alt="Short alt text" />
                            </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" class="form-control" runat="server" Text="Book Now" BackColor="#3465aa"
                                ForeColor="White" />
                            <p>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-image="images/r1.jpg"
                                data-target="#image-gallery">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/r1.jpg" alt="Short alt text">
                            </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="form-control" runat="server" Text="Book Now" BackColor="#3465aa"
                                ForeColor="White" />
                            <p>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="modal fade" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>
        </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="show-previous-image">
                            Previous</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 text-justify" id="image-gallery-caption">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="button" id="show-next-image" class="btn btn-default">
                            Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy. Use Asp.Net's LiteralControl to generate HTML components dynamically from server side.

Create a container division and assign an ID to it in HTML.

Now create an object of LiteralControl Class and append all your tags of images as a string parameter in object argument.

Use this above object creation inside the loop where data is coming from Database and dynamically assign the img-id and other CSS details in C# code itself referencing parent division id you created before.

[Follow this link to know more about Literal controls](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/literal-control-in-Asp-Net/)

For Example Let this is the code fetching data from DB

```
Sqldatareader dr=cmd.executereader();
while(dr.read()) 
{   
LiteralControl ob=new LiteralControl():
ob.text=@"<div id="displayroom" class="cards col-xs-4 col-xs-4 col- 
xs-4"><img src="img path from Db" class="img-responsive img-square"  
id="dr[0].ToString()"/><h3>Room Details: dr[3].ToString()</h3></div>";
}
dr.close();
```

The only thing you need to keep in mind is the proper conactination of diffrent values passing as a parameter to LiteralControl's object.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the info Mr. Nitin. Let me go through the link.

Comment: yeah sure. For any doubt , do let me know. This kind of concept i have applied in a product display page for a shopping site where product are displayed dynamically on the basis of database result. Hopefully this is the same scenario matching with you requirement

Comment: Yeah same like that.. I want to show available rooms pictures.

Comment: If you can share the code where data is fetching. I can help you to display Room pictures dynamically.

Comment: that would be great.. give me few minutes so i can share

Comment: appreciate you time and effort

Comment: Actually i was showing it on gridview earlier but found it old.

Comment: Can u please show me your code.. both image url and data i am getting in datatable....

Comment: Above answer is updated with a dummy code. Try to replicate the same functionality Using GridviewControl just to display images is not a good practice.

Comment: Yeah it's not.. that's why i'm trying to do something different.

Comment: Hi Mr. Nitin. I tried following code and got only last item image.......................                   

           if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ob.Text = "<img id='" + dr["ItemName"].ToString() + "' class='img-responsive' src='" + dr["ImageUrl"].ToString() + "'/><h3>Room Details: " + dr["ItemName"].ToString() + "</h3></div>";
                    
                }
            }

Comment: <div class="col-md-12" >
                <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                             <a class="thumbnail" href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-image="" data-target="#image-gallery">
                                                                                                  
                                 






   <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server">

                                </asp:Literal></a>
                            </div> </div></div>

Comment: Hi Dhawal, you got only last image because only the last item will be return by LiteralContainer to the HTML Dom. What you need to do is concacticate the html string every time the data comes from DB. see next comment for example

Comment: Kindly help me out to get all images using foreach.. and also want to add all images in literal block...

Comment: String roomHTML=null;       //Global HTML string generating dynamically.
LiteralControl ob=new LiteralControl();    //Global Literal Object.
for(.......)
{
roomHTML=roomHTML+ @"<img id='" + dr["ItemName"].ToString() + "' class='img-responsive' src='" + dr["ImageUrl"].ToString() + "'/><h3>Room Details: " + dr["ItemName"].ToString() + "</h3></div>";
}
ob.text=roomHTML;  // Return HTML string to DOM

In this way your complete html will be generate and returned to DOM.

Comment: Done with it @NitinSingh. You are amazing thanks for quick reply and support. gonna remember you brother..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156318/discussion-between-dhawal-and-nitin-singh).

Answer (score 0):

Inside button click create this code

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();    
sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
                sb.Append("$('#Photomodal').modal('show');");
                sb.Append(@"</script>");
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "PhotoModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
```

and your html, set data you can via button click.

```
<!--  Modal Starts here -->
    <div id="Photomodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="PhotoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                </div>
               your photo
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Sorry, if I don't help you